# Copy a linked list in C using append

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct node* copyList()
{ 
  //check if empty
  if(head==NULL){
  return NULL;}
  //create head
  struct node* p_head=head;//pointer to original head 
  struct node* newHead = NULL; //head of new list
  struct node* p_newHead=newHead;//pointer to new head
  while(p_head!=NULL)
    int data=p_head->data;
    m_appendNode(data, p_newHead);
    p_head=p_head->next;
  }
  return newHead;
}
```

When I run the program, my head remains null instead of building the list. Please let me know what I am missing. 
Thanks

EDIT:
append function

```
void m_appendNode(int data, struct node *newHead)
    {
    struct node* current=newHead;
    if(newHead!=NULL){
      while((current->next)!=NULL){
       current = current->next;
      }
      current->next=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      current->next->data=data;
      current->next->next=NULL;
      }
    else{
      struct node* newnode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      newnode->data=data;
      newHead=newnode;
      newnode->next=NULL;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Remember that in C arguments to functions are passed *by value*, meaning they are copied and the arguments in the function are just local variables which go out of scope when the function returns. Please do some searching for *emulating pass by reference in c*.

Comment: Why do you want to use `append()` ?; it effectively transforms your program to quadratic behaviour, where copying a list could have linear behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I'll assume there should have been a '{' after while in copyList.

Next, you have to understand what happens to values you're passing as arguments to a C function. What happens is the function **copies** the arguments and treats them as local variables which are forgotten after the function ends.

Trivial example is

```
void foo ( int a )
{
     a=10;
}
void bar ( void )
{
     int b = 1;
     foo ( b );
}
```

In bar after calling foo, the value of b (i.e. 1) is copied, foo changes it to 10 and then returns to bar, where b is still untouched and has a value of 1.

What you can do with this is pass a *pointer* to the function. In our example:

```
void foo ( int * a )
{
     *a=10;
}
void bar ( void )
{
     int b = 1;
     foo ( &b );
}
```

At the end of bar, b has indeed the value of 10.

Now let's get to your code, you're doing basically the same thing, where you pass pointer to newHead to m_appendNode and expect it to change. As I see it, you have two options, either pass pointer to a pointer (i.e. `struct node ** newHead`) and add a lot of asterisk everywhere or just make the function return `struct node *` and call it as `newHead = m_appendNode(data, p_newHead);`.

The latter is simpler, but I'd advise you to play around with the first option too to get a better hand of pointers.